# Boot device not found, 3F0 error after trying to install Ubuntu on HP Probook

Tags: boot, hp

I went to install Ubuntu on my PC and after the installation process it told me to restart the computer or test out the OS and explore or something, the first time I selected the latter and the second time I selected the former, both times when I try to install Ubuntu it gives me an error saying 'BootDevice not found, please install an operating system on your hard disk, Error 3F0'.

I'm assuming it's an error where the firmware can't find the OS because of some BIOS stuff. But I'm new to all of this so can some one please help me?